# How to check a custom attribute from $block?

Tags: php, magento2.3, custom-attributes

I have a **custom attribute** I need to **check** and if its '**Catalog**' then I want to hide the price as its not available on the site. If its one of the others then it should display. Originally I did this with

> `if($block->getDisplayValue() != 0.00)

`but now I am adding custom stuff that starts at a 0 cost and the price depends on options chosen. if the item can be purchased but doesnt have a price I would still like 0.00 to display.
I have used the attribute in other places starting from`$_product`but that is not working here. How do I start at the`$block` and get to my custom attribute within this file?

**my default.phtml:**
<

```
 ?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

    ?>

    <?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>
    <?php if($block->getDisplayValue() != 0.00){ ?>
        <span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
                <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
            <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
                <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
                <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
                data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
                data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
                class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>"
            ><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?></span>
            <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
                <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
                <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>" />
                <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
    <?php } ?>
```